# Building an XML file with a Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am looking to build an XML based on a Schema I was provided. Is there a tool that can reference these schema and guide through the process of building an an XML that adheres to the Schema? I am thinking along the lines of a linting tool that inform me what elements I have to add and any attributes that need to be completed along with their type restrictions?

I have a spec document I can use to understand when and why to use an element but it would be ideal if a linting tool could guide me through it.

I have found ways to validate XML based on Schemas but looking for a more real-time validation and linting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of tools that you can use. Some paid options are:

- [Oxygen XML Editor](https://www.oxygenxml.com/)
- [Liquid XML](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/)
- [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) (Note that you can also download the free Community edition which also includes XML editing features that can validate against an XSD as you code)

For a free option (and also cross-platform option), there's also using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), using this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rogalmic.vscode-xml-complete).